# How to change this method to a Set instead of ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, set

How could I change this method to remove all odd length strings in a TreeSet instead of an array?

```
    public void removeOddLength(ArrayList<String> list) {
        for (int i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).length() % 2 != 0) {
                list.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you not understand how to modify a method signature?  What have you tried so far?  Please see [this question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your method is already broken, in that it won't consider all the strings - if you have {"foo", "bar", "ab", "cd" } then you'll still be left with "bar" afterwards, because of the way you're iterating.

It's generally a pain to mutate a collection while you're iterating over it - it would be cleaner from an *API* perspective to just return a new collection with the even strings in afterwards.

However, you *can* do this with an iterator:

```
public void removeOddLength(Iterable<String> strings) {
    for (Iterator<String> it = strings.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        if (it.next().length() % 2 != 0) { 
            it.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

That will accept either a list *or* a set, or indeed any other iterable sequence - so long as the iterator supports removal, of course.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I couldn't think of a way to set a for loop to do that because I was trying to get an int value for each string. I wouldn't have thought of a hasNext(). One question however, what if the method is given a null parameter?

Comment: @aeipownu: then it will throw a NullPointerException. If you want it do do anything else, you'll need to code that yourself, e.g. Returning immediately. Ditto if you want to handle null values in the sequence.

Comment: What do you mean by returning?

Comment: I thought you couldn't return in a void method. Is there something obvious I am missing?

Comment: @aeipownu: you can return, just not a value - simply use return;